# Hacer responsive el tamaño de una tabla en Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me permite adaptar mi tabla en diferentes escalas pero cuando esta en modo telefono no se visualiza correctamente.

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card linehrcard ">
          <img src="../../img/general/img-cam-028.jpg" class="card-img-top"
            alt="Skyscrapers" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title text-center" style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 45px;">Tallas de Camarón</h1>
            <table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="tr-class-1 text-center " style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 15px;">
                    <th rowspan="2" data-field="SHELL">SHELL - ON</th>
                    <th colspan="2">PESO (GR)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" data-field="HEAD">HEAD - ON</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" data-field="HEADPE">PESO (GR)</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="tr-class-2 text-center " style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 15px;">
                    <th data-field="SHELLE">ENTERO</th>
                    <th data-field="SHELLD">DESCAB</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-center col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1" data-title="TALLAS CAMARON" data-object='{"key": "value"}'>
                    <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">16/20</td>
                    <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">44-35</td>
                    <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">28-23</td>
                    <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-1" data-title="HEAD - ON">10/20</td>
                    <td id="td-id-6" class="td-class-1" data-title="HEAD - ON">100-50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
                    <td id="td-id-7" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">21/25</td>
                    <td id="td-id-8" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">33-28</td>
                    <td id="td-id-9" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">22-18</td>
                    <td id="td-id-10" class="td-class-2" data-title="HEAD - ON">20/30</td>
                    <td id="td-id-11" class="td-class-2" data-title="HEAD - ON">50-33</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
                    <td id="td-id-12" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">26/30</td>
                    <td id="td-id-13" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">27-23</td>
                    <td id="td-id-14" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">17-15</td>
                    <td id="td-id-15" class="td-class-3" data-title="HEAD - ON">30/40</td>
                    <td id="td-id-16" class="td-class-3" data-title="HEAD - ON">33-25</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
                    <td id="td-id-17" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">31/35</td>
                    <td id="td-id-18" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">23-20</td>
                    <td id="td-id-19" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">15-13</td>
                    <td id="td-id-20" class="td-class-4" data-title="HEAD - ON">40/50</td>
                    <td id="td-id-21" class="td-class-4" data-title="HEAD - ON">25-20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
                    <td id="td-id-22" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">36/40</td>
                    <td id="td-id-23" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">19-17</td>
                    <td id="td-id-24" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">13-11</td>
                    <td id="td-id-25" class="td-class-5" data-title="HEAD - ON">60/70</td>
                    <td id="td-id-26" class="td-class-5" data-title="HEAD - ON">17-14</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-6" class="tr-class-6">
                    <td id="td-id-27" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">41/50</td>
                    <td id="td-id-28" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">17-14</td>
                    <td id="td-id-29" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">11-9</td>
                    <td id="td-id-30" class="td-class-6" data-title="HEAD - ON">70/80</td>
                    <td id="td-id-31" class="td-class-6" data-title="HEAD - ON">14-13</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-7" class="tr-class-7">
                    <td id="td-id-32" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">51/60</td>
                    <td id="td-id-33" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">14-12</td>
                    <td id="td-id-34" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">9-8</td>
                    <td id="td-id-35" class="td-class-7" data-title="HEAD - ON">80/100</td>
                    <td id="td-id-36" class="td-class-7" data-title="HEAD - ON">13-10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-8" class="tr-class-8">
                    <td id="td-id-37" class="td-class-8" data-title="SHELL - ON">61/70</td>
                    <td id="td-id-38" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">11-10</td>
                    <td id="td-id-39" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">7-6</td>
                    <td id="td-id-40" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">100/120</td>
                    <td id="td-id-41" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">10-8</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-9" class="tr-class-9">
                    <td id="td-id-42" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">71/90</td>
                    <td id="td-id-43" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">10-8</td>
                    <td id="td-id-44" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">6-5</td>
                    <td id="td-id-45" class="td-class-9" data-title="HEAD - ON">120/150</td>
                    <td id="td-id-46" class="td-class-9  " data-title="HEAD - ON">8-7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="tr-id-10" class="tr-class-10">
                    <td id="td-id-47" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">91/110</td>
                    <td id="td-id-48" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">8-6</td>
                    <td id="td-id-49" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">5-4</td>
                    <td id="td-id-50" class="td-class-10" data-title="HEAD - ON">150/200</td>
                    <td id="td-id-51" class="td-class-10" data-title="HEAD - ON">7-5</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve en modo telefono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podemos habilitar un scroll horizontal y que tu tabla tenga un ancho **mínimo** para que los elementos de adentro no se hagan demasiado pequeños, ya que el ancho de la tabla no sería inferior al ancho que le indicamos.

---

Entonces, hay que tener **un** contenedor padre que encierre a la tabla y a este mismo habilitarle el scroll horizontal.

Revisando tu HTML, tenemos a este contenedor padre, quien encierra a todo el contenido de la tabla:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Y a este otro contenedor que también encierra a todo el contenido de la tabla, en donde solo dibuja los bordes e indica que será una tarjeta, por la clase `card`:

```
<div class="card linehrcard">
```

Podemos tenerlo todo esto en uno solo, quedando así:

```
<div class="card linehrcard contenedor col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Y esa clase `contenedor` que agregamos servirá para habilitar el scroll y que su ancho ocupará todo el ancho máximo de la tabla:

```
.contenedor {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: max-content;
}
```

También vendría necesario tener otro contenedor padre **solo para centrar el contenido**, ya que esto no ocurría (se apegaba a la izquierda):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-4"> <!-- centro todo el contenido -->
  <div class="card linehrcard contenedor col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <!-- contenido -->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Ahora, veo que tu tabla tiene estas clases:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

De la cual sería incorrecto por que bastaría que esas clases solo lo tenga el contenedor padre y que **la tabla** ocupe todo el ancho de su contenedor padre. Entonces hagamos que la tabla ocupe todo el ancho de la rejilla, con `col-12`, quedando así:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" class="col-12">
```

Ahora vamos por los estilos de tus tablas, aquí indico que tendrá un ancho mínimo de `450px`, quiere decir que su ancho no será inferior a eso, y automáticamente aparecería el scroll horizontal (por el `overflow-y: auto;` del contenedor padre):

```
table {
  min-width: 450px;
}
```

Y por último, con la regla `@media`, indico que si el ancho de mi pantalla supera los `500px`, el título de la tarjeta tendrá un ancho fijo máximo, esto es para que en dispositivos pequeños el texto no se acople hacia abajo:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .card-title {
    width: max-content;
  }
}
```

**Código final:**

```css
.contenedor {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: max-content;
}

table {
  min-width: 450px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .card-title {
    width: max-content;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-4">
  <div class="card linehrcard contenedor col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="../../img/general/img-cam-028.jpg" class="card-img-top"
         alt="Skyscrapers" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1 class="card-title text-center" style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 45px;">Tallas de Camarón</h1>
      <table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" class="col-12">
        <thead>
          <tr class="tr-class-1 text-center " style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 15px;">
            <th rowspan="2" data-field="SHELL">SHELL - ON</th>
            <th colspan="2">PESO (GR)</th>
            <th rowspan="2" data-field="HEAD">HEAD - ON</th>
            <th rowspan="2" data-field="HEADPE">PESO (GR)</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tr-class-2 text-center " style="color: #0c1254; font-size: 15px;">
            <th data-field="SHELLE">ENTERO</th>
            <th data-field="SHELLD">DESCAB</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1" data-title="TALLAS CAMARON" data-object='{"key": "value"}'>
            <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">16/20</td>
            <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">44-35</td>
            <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-1" data-title="SHELL - ON">28-23</td>
            <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-1" data-title="HEAD - ON">10/20</td>
            <td id="td-id-6" class="td-class-1" data-title="HEAD - ON">100-50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
            <td id="td-id-7" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">21/25</td>
            <td id="td-id-8" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">33-28</td>
            <td id="td-id-9" class="td-class-2" data-title="SHELL - ON">22-18</td>
            <td id="td-id-10" class="td-class-2" data-title="HEAD - ON">20/30</td>
            <td id="td-id-11" class="td-class-2" data-title="HEAD - ON">50-33</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
            <td id="td-id-12" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">26/30</td>
            <td id="td-id-13" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">27-23</td>
            <td id="td-id-14" class="td-class-3" data-title="SHELL - ON">17-15</td>
            <td id="td-id-15" class="td-class-3" data-title="HEAD - ON">30/40</td>
            <td id="td-id-16" class="td-class-3" data-title="HEAD - ON">33-25</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
            <td id="td-id-17" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">31/35</td>
            <td id="td-id-18" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">23-20</td>
            <td id="td-id-19" class="td-class-4" data-title="SHELL - ON">15-13</td>
            <td id="td-id-20" class="td-class-4" data-title="HEAD - ON">40/50</td>
            <td id="td-id-21" class="td-class-4" data-title="HEAD - ON">25-20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
            <td id="td-id-22" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">36/40</td>
            <td id="td-id-23" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">19-17</td>
            <td id="td-id-24" class="td-class-5" data-title="SHELL - ON">13-11</td>
            <td id="td-id-25" class="td-class-5" data-title="HEAD - ON">60/70</td>
            <td id="td-id-26" class="td-class-5" data-title="HEAD - ON">17-14</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-6" class="tr-class-6">
            <td id="td-id-27" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">41/50</td>
            <td id="td-id-28" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">17-14</td>
            <td id="td-id-29" class="td-class-6" data-title="SHELL - ON">11-9</td>
            <td id="td-id-30" class="td-class-6" data-title="HEAD - ON">70/80</td>
            <td id="td-id-31" class="td-class-6" data-title="HEAD - ON">14-13</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-7" class="tr-class-7">
            <td id="td-id-32" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">51/60</td>
            <td id="td-id-33" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">14-12</td>
            <td id="td-id-34" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">9-8</td>
            <td id="td-id-35" class="td-class-7" data-title="HEAD - ON">80/100</td>
            <td id="td-id-36" class="td-class-7" data-title="HEAD - ON">13-10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-8" class="tr-class-8">
            <td id="td-id-37" class="td-class-8" data-title="SHELL - ON">61/70</td>
            <td id="td-id-38" class="td-class-7" data-title="SHELL - ON">11-10</td>
            <td id="td-id-39" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">7-6</td>
            <td id="td-id-40" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">100/120</td>
            <td id="td-id-41" class="td-class-8" data-title="HEAD - ON">10-8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-9" class="tr-class-9">
            <td id="td-id-42" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">71/90</td>
            <td id="td-id-43" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">10-8</td>
            <td id="td-id-44" class="td-class-9" data-title="SHELL - ON">6-5</td>
            <td id="td-id-45" class="td-class-9" data-title="HEAD - ON">120/150</td>
            <td id="td-id-46" class="td-class-9  " data-title="HEAD - ON">8-7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr-id-10" class="tr-class-10">
            <td id="td-id-47" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">91/110</td>
            <td id="td-id-48" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">8-6</td>
            <td id="td-id-49" class="td-class-10" data-title="SHELL - ON">5-4</td>
            <td id="td-id-50" class="td-class-10" data-title="HEAD - ON">150/200</td>
            <td id="td-id-51" class="td-class-10" data-title="HEAD - ON">7-5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/BaqVXoy).